# django.contrib.contenttypes.models.ContentType doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS

Tags: python, django, django-models, settings, django-apps

I am troubleshooting an NGINX/Django/UWSGI application for a customer, that has been broken beyond expectations. I've been debugging code, and re-writing for 30+ hours now and am at another hurdle that I can't seem to get past on my own.

```
[pid: 336873|app: 0|req: 1/1] 198.11.30.68 () {46 vars in 1070 bytes} [Mon Dec  5 10:04:42 2022] GET / => generated 0 bytes in 393 msecs (HTTP/1.1 500) 0 headers in 0 bytes (0 switches on core 0)
announcing my loyalty to the Emperor...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/django/django_venv/django_site/wsgi.py", line 26, in application
    get_wsgi_application();
  File "/home/django/django_venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
    WSGIHandler();
  File "/home/django/django_venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 127, in __init__
    self.load_middleware()
  File "/home/django/django_venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 40, in load_middleware
    middleware = import_string(middleware_path)
  File "/home/django/django_venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py", line 17, in import_string
    module = import_module(module_path)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/django/django_venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/middleware.py", line 3, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.backends import RemoteUserBackend
  File "/home/django/django_venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/backends.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.models import Permission
  File "/home/django/django_venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 5, in <module>
    from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
  File "/home/django/django_venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/contenttypes/models.py", line 133, in <module>
    class ContentType(models.Model):
  File "/home/django/django_venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 116, in __new__
    "INSTALLED_APPS." % (module, name)
RuntimeError: Model class django.contrib.contenttypes.models.ContentType doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS.
[pid: 336874|app: 0|req: 1/2] 198.11.30.68 () {46 vars in 1049 bytes} [Mon Dec  5 10:04:42 2022] GET /favicon.ico => generated 0 bytes in 393 msecs (HTTP/1.1 500) 0 headers in 0 bytes (0 switches on core 0)
announcing my loyalty to the Emperor...
```

So I can't get around this error message, and I am not sure how to move forward.

Also, here is my settings.py. Literally any help would be appreciated. Just going in circles right now.

```py
import django.utils
from pathlib import Path
import six
import localsettings as secret
import urls
import sys
import os
import django
django.setup()
# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = <removed for privacy>

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = [<removed for privacy>]
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'wsgi.application',
    'acknowledgments.apps.AcknowledgmentsConfig',
    'data_sources.apps.DataSourcesConfig',
    'home.apps.HomeConfig',
    'igv.apps.IgvConfig',
    'organisms.apps.OrganismsConfig',
    'samples.apps.SamplesConfig',
    'search.apps.SearchConfig',
    'summary.apps.SummaryConfig',
    ]
#import django.contrib.contenttypes.models.ContentType
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'urls'
SITE_ID = 1
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'django_site.templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = "wsgi.application"


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#databases


DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': secret.db_name,
        'USER': secret.db_user,
        'PASSWORD': secret.db_token,
        'HOST': secret.db_host,
        }
    }



# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = '<removed for privacy>'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static/admin")
STATIC_URL ="static/admin/"

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
```